# Make HTML elements, in separate containers of different width, the same width, only with CSS

Tags: javascript, css

I'm currently trying to make `.product-box` elements that are in a `#product-slider` slider the same width as the `.product-box` elements that are in a `#products` Bootstrap grid.

Here's the layout we're talking about:
[image: Here's the layout we're talking about]

Bootstrap is unimportant for the question here. Let's assume all `#products .row .product-box` are about 25% width, and some padding on the sides.

The problem is that the slider width depends on the number of elements it contains. It has an indefinite width.

`.container` width is not necessarily equal to viewport width. So I can't just go `width: 25vw` for the `#product-slider .product-box` boxes.

### Current solution

- I create every `#product-slider .product-box` with a `style="width:200px;"` so that their default width is not too shabby
- Then I execute this JS code as soon as the `#products .product-box` are created:

```
// Get a reference product box from the grid
var productBox = document.querySelector('#products .product-box');

// Get its width
var referenceWidth = Math.round(productBox.getBoundingClientRect().width);

// Apply its width to all .product-box in the slider
[].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('#product-slider .product-box')).forEach(elem =>{
    elem.style.width = referenceWidth+'px';
});
```

- And I also execute this JS code on resize events and such

### Problems with my solution

My solution works but above JS script has to be executed ASAP so that the jump between `width:200px;` and found width is not too visible. If it's executed too late, the browser has the time to render a frame or two with the initial width and there's an inelegant jump.

### Questions

- Is there a full CSS solution for this problem? To my knowledge there is none, but my CSS knowledge is *ancient*.
- If not, is there a more elegant solution to this problem?

Thanks,

Comment: No, css cannot equalize widths in separate containers.

Comment: If the only problem is an inelegant jump, consider using a loader. This shows as long the JS code executes. After that, show the rendered page.

Comment: A loader has to take vertical space, and the vertical space taken by my .product-box items is proportional to their width, which is unknown. So even with a loader, there would be a jump. Note that by executing the javascript code directly after the boxes creation in the markup, I get no jump at all. But I find a bit inelegant to run a script in the middle of a page, too.

Comment: You could _hide_ all but the first four slider items initially - then a 25% width for the remaining ones, should result in the exact width, as the 25% of the columns in the other element. And then your JavaScript can go and fix the width and show all the items "later", without it being too visually disruptive.

Comment: Or, if this HTML is generated by some server-side script, so that you would _know_ the number of images there already, you could add an additional inner wrapper, that you give a percentage of the width of the parent - 100% for four items, 200% for eight, 150% for six ... If you make that inner container a flex container, all the slides could take the appropriate fraction of the width automatically.

Comment: Problem is the page is responsive, it's 4 items on certains screen widths, 3 on others, 1 on mobile...